# How to get Message When setInterval(); stops

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Im using `SetInterval();` function to display time ,and sometimes it stop's it's not a regular behavior ,it just stops .
Here below is my code :

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    setInterval(settime, 1000);
 function settime() 
 {
    try
    {
        var curtime = new Date();
        var curhour = curtime.getHours();
        var curmin = curtime.getMinutes();
        var cursec = curtime.getSeconds();
        var time = "";
        if(curhour == 0) curhour = 12;
        time = (curhour > 12 ? curhour - 12 : curhour) + ":" +
             (curmin < 10 ? "0" : "") + curmin + ":" +
             (cursec < 10 ? "0" : "") + cursec + " " +
             (curhour > 12 ? "PM" : "AM");
        var currentTime = new Date()
        var month = currentTime.getMonth();
        var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
        var day = currentTime.getDay();
        var dayString = "";
        if(day == 0)
            dayString = "Sunday";
        if(day == 1)
            dayString = "Monday";
        if(day == 2)
            dayString = "Tuesday";
        if(day == 3)
            dayString = "Wednesday";
        if(day == 4)
            dayString = "Thursday";
        if(day == 5)
            dayString = "Friday";
        if(day == 6)
            dayString = "Saturday";
        var fullDate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
        document.date.clock.value = "Date : "+fullDate;
        document.date.clock1.value = "Time : " + time;
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        alert("Errorr from Function");
    }
}
```

So is there a way how to catch ,when `setInterval();` stops and to start it again !!

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle or describe steps to deterministically reproduce that behaviour? `setInterval` doesn't just stop randomly.

Comment: @davin yes it does ,actually it happens only at a specific Computer (and there it should work) ,so i dont care if it stops or not ,i just want to get Messaged if it's stooped ,or when !!

Comment: Cody, what I'm asking is, is there consistency in the pattern. Does it always stop after a certain amount of time? Maybe in a particular browser/version? How do you know it stops - have you added a `console.log` to the beginning of the function and verified?

Comment: @davin it stop's updating the time ,and i didn't implement console.log and there is no consistency that's why im so confused about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setInterval is notoriously problematic. Use recursive calls to setTimeout instead.

http://www.erichynds.com/javascript/a-recursive-settimeout-pattern/

Comment: Problematic? I don't think so. You might not think it's a good pattern to use, but it functions as intended. Otherwise what you are describing is a bug in a particular implementation.